# Image Overlay on Statusbar

Tags: android, overlay, statusbar

I have added the primary dark color on the status bar to make it the color of my toolbar.

[image: Coloured Status Bar]

But I have a slide up panel with an image on the top (screenshot) which I need to overlay onto the status bar. Its currently like the screenshot below.
[image: Should be overlaying the image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the below in your AppTheme style in values-v21 folder (styles.xml) :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

By default, the status bar color is determined by "colorPrimaryDark". Apply the above theme to your specific activity in androidManifest.xml. (parent theme can be anything)

Comment: Worked for me after adding this statement after the two above.
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>